# Do they still have border controls in the highways when you travel to croatia like before?

Tags: borders

I am Swedish and I have never been to Croatia and recently I have friends who will join me for a roadtrip to Croatia and they are not all swedish. My GF is chinese and she has a schengen visa but I travelled with her to spain with car and never had the hassle of border control. She is paranoid of control as she was kept in USA at Border for 4 days because she is a muslim -chinese. I will avoid croatia if it is still so strict on  check ups after the entered the schengen

thanks
Fabian

Comment: They kept her for 4 days at the border just because she is Muslim? what border is that?

Comment: Croatia does not have enough resources to detain all the Muslims crossing its borders for four days.  But of course most of those have Bosnian or other Balkan passports, and I suppose there are far fewer of them now that Croatia is in the EU.  I have no idea what they will think of a Chinese passport.  Given that she has a Schengen visa, however, I doubt they would look twice at it.

Comment: The crucial point is whether the Sehengen visa your GF holds is multiple-entry. Croatia allow holders of Schengen visas to enter, but the visa must hot be fully used (there must be remaining days and entries). And of course another entry is needed to return from Croatia to Schengen Zone.

Comment: If she was held for four days at the US border, I can completely understand she is worried and I would not classify those worries as *paranoid*.

Answer (score 1):

I crossed the border from Slovenia into Croatia a few weeks after they joined the EU (but not Schengen yet), it was merely a few guys checking your passport and stamping it, not even one question asked about who I am or what I was going to do in Croatia, neither anyone else accompanying me. I believe the situation must be even smoother now, given that Croatia is hopefully joining Schengen [soon](http://www.balkaninsight.com/en/article/croatia-to-apply-for-schengen-in-mid-2015).

Comment: 7 years later, Croatia is finally joining the Schengen Area in a few days!

Answer (score 1):

Border police in former eastern Europa can behave different from most of Europa. Some years ago I was travelling with a Australian student - who had all the proper paperwork. However, he was denied entry into the Czech Republic. This was before they became a part of Schengen (2004 or so).

They had no reason to do it, it was purely based on a whim.

Call the Croatian embassy in Sweden - http://www.embassypages.com/missions/embassy3265/ and ask what you need to do to be sure to get entry. Get a name and some contact info you can call if you have problems.

Comment: The story of an Australian tourist being denied entry to Czechia for no reason is very hard to believe...